# Azure Boards : Completed Work for Epic/Feature

Tags: azure-devops, report, azure-boards

I need to get the total completed work on Epic/Feature .
Epic->Feature->UserStory->Tasks are linked with parent/child hierarchy.
How to use sum of completed work on an EPIC or a Feature, considering all the tasks that are child to them have the completed work in it.
Query Editor doesn't have an option to do sum function.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Custom Rollup on the backlog level:

[image]

The result:

[image]

Check this document: [Display rollup progress or totals in Azure Boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/display-rollup?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process)

Here you can find additional suggestions to rollup work: [Rollup of work and other fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/support-rollup-of-work-and-other-fields?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Yeah it’s available in backlog but can’t export the data. Even if I use option to create query of the results it would remove the rollup columns. 
Basically I am trying to get the exact result available in backlog . Get the total work completed for a feature . 
Raw data exported from query editor will have only one level of parent mapping . Means task is linked to user story and hence unless I apply some advanced formulas in excel 
I can’t achieve my objective now